# Displaying set value in text box

Tags: html

So I've got a problem.
I've created a text box like that:

```
 <input type="text" id="search" name="search" class="myText" value="Search for a keyword" onclick="value=''"/>
```

My problem basically is that after I press the text box to write a text of my own, and then press some other place on the screen, the value I set at start (Search for a keyword) will not be displayed once again.
I've tried everything. How do I make it display again once I've pressed some other place on the screen?

Comment: I think you need to make your question clearer. So when you enter a value in this text box, and then click on another form element, the value you've entered disappears and is replaced with 'Search for a keyword', is that correct?

Comment: You didn't get me right, my bad. I would like to do just what you described. As you said, I would like the value I entered to disapper and be replaced with 'Search for a keyword' once I press some other place on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `onclick="value=''`

You are basically saying, empty the box whenever I click on it.

If you can use html5, you can use:

```
<input type="text" id="search" name="search" class="myText" placeholder="Search for a keyword" />
```

And you can style it as well:

```
<style type="text/css">
    ::-moz-placeholder {color:#ddd;}
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder {color:#ddd;}
    :-ms-input-placeholder {color:#ddd;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the placeholder attribute :

Example :

```
<input name="Email" type="text" id="Email" value="email@abc.com" placeholder="Enter your mail" />
```

Comment: THank you very much, it works. bY the way, is there any way to change the color of the text in the placeholder? it's grey and ugly :p

Comment: Yes you can using Css : you can find examples there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css

Comment: Remi - I gave you an upvote, you were a tad faster than I was.